# Meteor: Passing Session values from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, meteor

I am using the following code on the `client side` to set the Session variable:

```
Template.download.events({
    'click button': function() {
        var clientid=Random.id();
        UserSession.set("songsearcher", clientid);
        console.log(clientid + UserSession.get("songsearcher"));
```

I am using the following pacakge: [Meteor-User-session](https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-user-session), which will explain the use of `UserSession` in place of `Session`.

Now, this works fine.

But When I try to get the Session variable on the server side, which is the reason I am using the above mentioned Package, it gives me the following error in the Developer tools:

```
UserSession.set @ VM106 benjaminrh_user-session.js?6483f8d2c775bfb11a28a707104fc5cbd79bb6bb:61Template.download.events.click button @ VM120 client.js?c0ec6b46a653f555e1b4403f9469cd8483ddc49c:13(anonymous function) @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3502Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476(anonymous function) @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3501(anonymous function) @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2543Blaze._withCurrentView @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2197(anonymous function) @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2542(anonymous function) @ VM112 blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:839jQuery.event.dispatch @ VM108 jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a:4698jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ VM108 jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a:4366
```

Is this because the package I am using is Deprecated, or you know Meteor changedtheir own code? And if it is, what is the way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your need. Why do you want to share Session with Server ? 
Session is client-side only, but you can send value if your session with Meteor Methods, or in your subscription. In the second case, your sbscription can be reactive with the Session dependancy.

Could you give us more information to help you ?

Comment: I sent the Session variable via Methods, and that solved the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to fix rhis and that is,to add the account system, because that it is the only thing that the Meteor.userId() function works on.

```
meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password
```